# unable to get jpg image using python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

As i want to extract jpg links only but it print whole links from https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
content= soup.find_all('div',class_='col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3') 
for item in content:
    
    try:
        images = item.find('img',{'class':'tile-image c-product-tile__img'},src=True)
    except:
        images=''
    print(images)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `images['src']` to print out the attribute.

Comment: it print in base64

Comment: `from base64 import b64decode`
 `b64decode("AAAAAA")`

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27 viewBox=%270 0 1 1%27%3E%3C/svg%3E

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong output. As you've shown in your second image, the `src` attribute of many elements is links to normal, working images.